# Accessing a view's function from another view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, function, razor

Firstly, I'm beginner of the MVC.

I have a controller named `FinanceController`. I have two views named `StoreEvaluationForm` and `SendStoreEvaluationToPdf` of this control. I want to call a first view's `public static` function, which is defined in `@functions`, from second view.

I guess views have hidden class in mvc. Because I realized when I mouse over first view's function, VS shows its class named `_Page_Views_Finance_StoreEvaluationForm_cshtml` and its namespace named ASP. However I couldn't find any way to accessing another view's function. In second view ASP namespace has only its class named `_Page_Views_Finance_SendStoreEvaluationToPdf_cshtml`.

To be clear, function in the view is a C# function not a javascript function. Its definition is:

```
@functions
{
    public static string NumberFormatter(double? number, bool percent = false)
    {
        return number == null ? null : string.Format("{0}{1}", number.Value.ToString("N2"), percent ? "%" : null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be a better idea to move the shared function to a helper class. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: There is no reason. I also can move it to controller class. But I just want to know. Is there a way to access a view's function from another view which are in same controller.

Comment: With MVC there should be no functions in the view. To share code or part of a view create a partial view. If it is JavaScript put it in a script file and reference it in both places.

Comment: It is not a javascript function. It is a C# function. I added the definition of it.

Comment: Yes, this is the wrong way to do it, even if you can, don't. MVC is a pattern, stick to using that pattern the correct way

Comment: Dude, I know but I just want to know if it can be accessible or not? Whether it is or not I want to learn. Even if it is not accessible there is no problem. Can you tell me it is or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved. I tried it with the default MVC project in Visual Studio 2015.

**Content of `About` view:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

@functions
{
    public static string DoStuff()
    {
        return "Content from About view.";
    }
}
```

**Content of `Index` view:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@_Page_Views_Home_About_cshtml.DoStuff()

... (other stuff)
```

In `Index` view there is a red squiggly line below `_Page_Views_Home_About_cshtml` displaying :

> The name _Page_Views_Home_About_cshtml does not exist in the current context

Despite the error message, the application builds successfully and I can see the message from the `About` view when navigating to `/Home/Index`.

[image: View]